# Unable to implement JSNLog on .NET 4.5 MVC application

Tags: c#, logging, error-logging, jsnlog

**Issue:** I am trying to use JSNLog in MVC application(Target Framework: .NET 4.5). I am getting **"JSN Log does not exist in the current context"** error.

I tried installing **JSNLog 2.28.0**, but it was showing:

Could not install package 'JSNLog 2.28.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

So, I have installed these following packages for logging:

1. JSN Log v-2.27.1
2. JSNLog.Log4Net v-2.27.1
3. log4Net v-2.0.8

This same thing i have done earlier on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and in that time it worked very easily. Is there something i am missing?

**My Steps are:**

1. Created a MVC application from VS 2017.
2. Installed log4net and added server side logging.(This is working fine)
3. Downloaded JSNLog & JSNLog.Log4Net
4. JSNLog Configurations are added in Web.Config automatically.
5. Added **@Html.Raw(JSNLog.JavascriptLogging.Configure())** in the view. (This is working for .NET 4.6.1 only).
6. Added my own script for JSN Log.

**My Sample code is given below:**

I am getting this below error on Index.cshtml page:

[image: Index_cshtml]

Here is my JSNLog configuration in Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="jsnlog" type="JSNLog.ConfigurationSectionHandler, JSNLog" requirePermission="false" /><sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <!-- prevent log4net from locking the file, otherwise integration tests cannot remove it for each test-->
      <param name="LockingModel" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <file value="Logs\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate | %level | %logger | %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="TRACE" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.logger" type="JSNLog.LoggerHandler, JSNLog" />
    </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

<jsnlog productionLibraryPath="~/Scripts/jsnlog.min.js">
    </jsnlog><common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal.Log4NetFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal" />
    </logging>
  </common>
```

**I tried using jsnlog dll from .NET 4.6.1 project.**

Here that previous error was gone, but it is giving this error now: POST http://localhost:xxxxx/jsnlog.logger 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Browser Console Error]

Comment: As a solution i changed my MVC project framework to 4.6.1 and then its working. I guess JSN Log is not compatible with .NET 4.5 version.